# Marketing Cloud Business Unit

Tags: marketing-cloud, marketing-cloud-connect, sfmc-business-unit, unsubscribe, sync

Good Day to everyone.
In our MC account, we have a parent business unit and a child business unit.
In the Parent BU, we have settings that allow subscribers to unsubscribe from all business units in the Enterprise.

In the child BU, we have settings that allow subscribers to unsubscribe from this business unit only.

We want to change the settings of child BU from Subscribers will only be unsubscribed from this business unit to -> Subscribers will be unsubscribed from all business units in the Enterprise. Similar to the settings of Parent BU.

Is this feasible? If we change these settings, will it impact any existing functionality or automation? Is there any reporting that will be affected by it?

Plus, it is advisable to make this change because our goal is for every contact to have the same preference in each BU business unit, whether it's Production or parent.

Thanks.